# Detect access keys in SonarQube with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate SonarQube with an Angular 12 application. Sonar detects any username and password but does not detect any access key (API key) if it is hardcoded value. How can I write custom rules for this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to add a custom rule before trying out this SonarCube plugin:
https://github.com/Skyscanner/sonar-secrets

> Sonar Secrets plugin for SonarQube™ is designed to identify hardcoded
> secrets such as passwords, API keys, AWS credentials, tokens, etc. In
> line with best security practices it is recommended to use a
> credentials store (such as credstash or Vault) to contain all secrets,
> and refer to these using identifiers, such that the source code will
> never contain any cleartext secret.
>
> This plugin supports Java and JavaScript.

If you still need a custom rule,

> there are three ways to add coding rules to SonarQube:
>
> - Writing a SonarQube plugin in Java that uses SonarQube APIs to add new rules
> - Adding XPath rules directly through the SonarQube web interface
> - Importing Generic Issue Reports generated by an independently run tool

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/

You can find more info in a docs article about security-related sonarqube rules here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-rules/

Comment: Check also this article on Medium: https://medium.com/@SkyscannerEng/introducing-sonar-secrets-32e36e1bbc97